# как разпарсить картинки из определённых div'ов, а не из всего сайта?

Tags: python

написал простой парсер, который собирает все изображения с сайта и отправляет мне в телегу через бота. теперь появилась проблема с фильтрацией данных изображений, так как вместе с нужным контентом, также, присылает аватарки пользователей.
мой код:

```
import telebot, urllib.request;
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://*имя сайта*').read()
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = parsed_html.findAll('img', src=True)

for link in links:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,link["src"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам не следует сразу искать изображения.
Найдите сначала блоки, изображения из которых вам нужны, или исключите те, которые ненужны, и только затем в цикле по каждому из этих блоков, ищите изображения внутри блока

```
img_divs = parsed_html.findAll("div", {"class": "div-contain-img"})
for div in img_divs:
    div.findAll('img', src=True)
```

Comment: "div-contain-img" надо заменить на название интересующего класса?

Comment: именно. можете посмотреть в документации есть ли там поиск но несколькольким классам или по регуляркам